# Programmatically open a file in Visual Studio (2010)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, file-io

I'm building a VS package, and I'm trying to send a command from the package to Visual Studio to open up a user selected file in a new tab (just like a user would do it by going to File -> Open...).

I remember seeing at some point how to do this. Can anybody refresh my memory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you want one of:

1. [IVsUIShellOpenDocument.OpenStandardEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsuishellopendocument.openstandardeditor.aspx)
2. [DTE.OpenFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._dte.openfile.aspx)
3. [DTE.ItemOperations.OpenFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.itemoperations.openfile(VS.80).aspx)

In the end, I think they all boil down to the same behavior.

Comment: Hi Chris...I don't get it though. My DTE object doesn't have any of these methods. And if I try to make a new DTE object, it gives me an error. Any suggestions?

Comment: What assemblies are you referencing (i.e. where is your `DTE` type coming from)?  The `DTE` objects mentioned above are coming from EnvDTE.dll, so try adding a reference to that.  What is the error you get when trying to create a new `DTE` object?  Is it a compile-time or runtime error?

Comment: I am referencing all of the ENVDTE80/100 assemblies.

The error is compile-time: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'EnvDTE80.DTE2'

Also, I am running this in a VS Package (since I am building a VS package).

Comment: Is there a way to open it in an existing tab?

Answer (score 8):

I like to use the DTE method ExecuteCommand("commandName") as you can test the command in the VS Command Window

In this case ExecuteCommand("File.OpenFile")

You can add parameters to the command in a second optional string parameter if you wish.

Comment: Somehow I can't find this method. Is it still available in .NET 4?

Comment: I've just created an addin in VS2010 - the template creates a private variable:

private DTE2 _applicationObject;

You can get the ExecuteCommand from there...

Comment: Ah, yes, I see what you mean.

The thing was that now I'm building a Visual Studio Package. I can create a Visual Studio Add-In as well, but then, how would I create an instance of the add-in, that I can use in the VS package, but the add-in would still keep its _applicationObject.

I hope you understand what I mean, it's somehow like using the add-in object (_applicationObject) from a WinForms application.

Comment: Works also with Visual Studio 2017 and `EnvDTE80.DTE2`: `dte2.ExecuteCommand("File.OpenFile", pathToYourFile);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function: [VsShellUtilities.OpenDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.vsshellutilities.opendocument?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

If you call it from VSPackage method it looks like:

```
VsShellUtilities.OpenDocument(this, fileName);
```

Namespace: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell`

Assemblies: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0.dll`,
`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0.dll`

Also it has two overloads which return additional information for opened document.

NOTE: This function is available in VS 2015 and later.