# How to find Class/Entity complete namespace where it is used in solution/source code with their line number of usage(object creation)

Tags: c#, .net

I want to write a program in c# that extracts Class/Entity complete namespace where it is used in solution/source code with their line number of usage.

Below is the code of mini to get class references without line numbers

var nameSpaces = typeOf(Test).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetTypes().ToArray();

//... Here Test is Class

The output will be of program

[image]

Comment: Note that source code lines are not stored in compiled assemblies that do not have debugging information stored (typically those built in Release)

Comment: then Could suggest me any solution to it?

Comment: @saifullah regarding your recently closed question about opening a file programmatically (which I cannot comment on because it's closed), you can do what you're after using DTE. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/q/5039226/24874 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/2865909/24874. You'll need to read more about DTE.